# jOOQ: How to select an empty array "[]" in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jooq

I would like to produce SQL that is essentially the equivalent of `array[]` or `[]` using jOOQ's DSL so that it's portable between dialects.

Unfortunately in Kotlin, none of these work:

```
// Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match.
// public open fun <T : Any!> array(vararg values: TypeVariable(T)!): Field<Array<(out) TypeVariable(T)!>!> defined in org.jooq.impl.DSL
// public open fun <T : Any!> array(vararg fields: Field<TypeVariable(T)!>!): Field<Array<(out) TypeVariable(T)!>!> defined in org.jooq.impl.DSL
DSL.array()

DSL.array(null as Any?)      // Produces a non-empty array
DSL.array(emptyList<Any>())  // Produces a non-empty array
```

Is there any way to do this, or something like an `DSL.emptyArray()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why passing `emptyList<Any>` didn't work

The `Collection` accepting overload of [`DSL.array()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#array(java.util.Collection)) expects a `Collection<? extends Field<T>>`, i.e. a collection of column expressions, not a `Collection<? extends T>`, which would be a collection of bind values. We can't have both overloads for the usual type erasure reasons, so only the more generic version is offered. But you're passing a `List<Any>`, not a `List<Field<*>>`. You could change your code to:

```kotlin
DSL.array(emptyList<Field<*>>())
```

#### Why passing `null` didn't work

When you pass `null`, the varargs overload is resolved, which corresponds to `ARRAY[NULL]` in SQL, an array containing a `NULL` value.

#### How to call the varargs overload

If you want to work with the varargs overloads, then just pass an empty array:

```kotlin
DSL.array(arrayOf<String>())
```

Because array types are reified in Java, both varargs overloads exist:

- `array(T...)`: Accepting bind values
- `array(Field<T>...)`: Accepting column expressoins

#### Regarding array types

If you're using PostgreSQL, you'll probably have to cast that array expression explicitly to e.g. `SQLDataType.VARCHAR.getArrayDataType()`

```kotlin
DSL.array(arrayOf<String>()).cast(SQLDataType.VARCHAR.getArrayDataType())
```

#### Using bind values as an alternative

You can always use [bind values](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/indexed-parameters/) or [inline values](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/inlined-parameters/) as well:

```kotlin
DSL.value(arrayOf<String>())
DSL.inline(arrayOf<String>())
```

In this case, the array type is known to jOOQ, and you don't need to cast it explicitly anymore.